# attach Database without Overwriting the original

Tags: sql-server, restore

New to this, We have needed to do a system restore of a SQL DB the IT co have provided us with a copy of the MDF and LDF files, I need to attach these without overwriting the existing files.

But I get this message when trying to attach the log file.

Directory lookup for the file "H:\T007.Data\A&S Growers_OLD_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.). (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5133)

Comment: What do you mean by "not overwrite" as in create a separate database, or do you mean you want the "new" data to be added to your existing one.

Comment: As for the error, show us the SQL you're using to get said error; likely the SQL Server account doesn't have access to the path.

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24610/copy-rename-db-so-i-can-attach-both-copies) might help.

Comment: Do you REALLY have a physical drive H: on the machine hosting your sql server instance? Or is this a mapped drive? Is that a mapped drive on your server machine or is that on your local client PC (running SSMS) that is mapped to <?>?